# RxSwift Wait For Observable to Complete

Tags: swift, reactivex

I'm new to rxswift and here's my problem:

Suppose I have observable of actions: Observable.of("do1", "do2", "do3")

Now this observable mapped to function that returns observable:

```
let actions = Observable.of("do1", "do2", "do3")

func do(action: String) -> Observable<Result> {
       // do something
       // returns observable<Result>
}

let something = actions.map { action in return do(action) } ???
```

How can I wait for do1 to complete first, then execute do2, then do3?

Edit: Basically i want to achieve sequential execution of actions. do3 waits for do2 result, do2 waits for do1 result.

Edit2: I've tried using flatmap and subscribe, but all actions runs in parallel.

Comment: Add some more details. What are you exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 9):

> How can I wait for do1 to complete first, then execute do2, then do3?

I think `concatMap` solves the problem.

Lets say we have some service and some actions we need to perform on it, for instance a backend against with we'd like to authenticate and store some data. Actions are **login** and **store**. We can't **store** any data if we aren't logged in, so we need to wait **login** to be completed before processing any **store** action.

While `flatMap`, `flatMapLatest` and `flatMapFirst` execute observables in parallel, `concatMap` waits for your observables to complete before moving on.

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let service: [String:Observable<String>] = [
    "login": Observable.create({
        observer in
        observer.onNext("login begins")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
            observer.onNext("login completed")
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }),
    "store": Observable.create({
        observer in
        observer.onNext("store begins")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
            observer.onNext("store completed")
            observer.onCompleted()
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }),
]

// flatMap example
let observeWithFlatMap = Observable.of("login", "store")
    .flatMap {
        action in
        service[action] ?? .empty()
    }

// flatMapFirst example
let observeWithFlatMapFirst = Observable.of("login", "store")
    .flatMapFirst {
        action in
        service[action] ?? .empty()
    }

// flatMapLatest example
let observeWithFlatMapLatest = Observable.of("login", "store")
    .flatMapLatest {
        action in
        service[action] ?? .empty()
    }

// concatMap example
let observeWithConcatMap = Observable.of("login", "store")
    .concatMap {
        action in
        service[action] ?? .empty()
    }

// change assignment to try different solutions
//
// flatMap: login begins / store begins / store completed / login completed
// flatMapFirst: login begins / login completed
// flatMapLatest: login begins / store begins / store completed
// concatMap: login begins / login completed / store begins / store completed

let observable = observeWithConcatMap

observable.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just face the same problem, and finally found the solution.
I expect my devices will do disconnect followed by one another, so I did as follow:

I just create the func like

```
func disconnect(position: WearingPosition) -> Completable{
    print("test run")
    return Completable.create { observer in
          print("test run 2")    
          // Async process{
          //       observer(.complete)
          // }
                 
          return Disposables.create() 
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
self.disconnect(position: .left_wrist).andThen(Completable.deferred({
        
        return self.disconnect(position: .right_wrist)
        
    })).subscribe(onCompleted: {
        // do some things
        
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

The key is the usage of " Completable.deferred "

I have tested with the "test run" printed

Answer (score -1):

Use `flatMap` or `flatMapLatest`. You can find more about them at [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can `flatMap` and `subscribe` to the `Result` observable sequence by calling `subscribe(on:)` on the final output.

```
actions
    .flatMap { (action) -> Observable<Result> in
        return self.doAction(for: action)
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (result) in
        print(result)
    })

func doAction(for action: String) -> Observable<Result> {
    //...
}
```

Read:

- https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-and-master-%EF%B8%8F-the-basics-of-rxswift-in-10-minutes-818ea6e0a05b

Comment: I've tried using your method, but all actions run in parallel

Comment: @buhutz I do understand that you want to process `do2` only after `do1`'s result but could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve by providing a real world scenario rather than an abstract concept.

Comment: Sorry if im not that clear, go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381467/rxswift-mvvm-coordinator-pattern-how-to-wait-for-coordinator-result-sequent for my new question